# Can bussed grounds in an audio patchbay create a ground loop?

Tags: audio, noise, ground, ground-loop, signal-routing

I am working on a project to create a patchbay-style interface for guitar pedals, wherein a set of guitar pedals can be routed in different configurations using TT cables (like the patchbay interfaces used in most recording studios; think of a cross between [this guitar pedal patching interface](https://boredbrainmusic.com/product/patchulator-v2/) and [this studio patchbay](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/PS48DB25F--bittree-prostudio-ps48db25f-desktop-48-point-tt-db25-patchbay?mrkgadid=3341928026&mrkgcl=28&mrkgen=gpla&mrkgbflag=0&mrkgcat=studio&recording&acctid=21700000001645388&dskeywordid=92700046934908907&lid=92700046934908907&ds_s_kwgid=58700005285215130&ds_s_inventory_feed_id=97700000007215323&dsproductgroupid=603911963232&product_id=PS48DB25F&prodctry=US&prodlang=en&channel=online&storeid=&device=c&network=g&matchtype=&adpos=largenumber&locationid=9004347&creative=353503474066&targetid=pla-603911963232&campaignid=2005216453&awsearchcpc=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwu7OIBhCsARIsALxCUaORX4fo0ZNR_bcolYcrLFMbk9xaIYnxdZrDLZ5loErtQuJfZV57grMaAo-FEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)).

In my prototyping for this project I have been experiencing some noise issues when cables/pedals are left unconnected in the vicinity of the patchbay chassis, which seem to immediately disappear as soon as a ground connection is made between the various devices (my guitar amplifier and several guitar pedals powered by a one-spot 9 V supply). This makes me think that an obvious solution would be bussing the grounds within the patchbay, such that all of the grounds are connected regardless of cable position.

One of my collaborators is pretty adamant about not doing this, saying that it will create the potential for ground loops. However, my understanding is that ground loops are created by connection of devices in the same signal flow path to separate AC power circuits (as shown in the image below), rather than by the internal low voltage patching of the devices.

[image]

I'd like to keep my solution to the noise issue I'm experiencing as elegant as possible, so I wanted to clear up whether this supposed ground loop issue was a real concern or just audiophile superstition. Can bussing low-voltage grounds in this type of patchbay create a ground loop?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a star topology - connect each earth directly back to one common earthing point. This eliminates ground loops by design.

Take care though that you don't have any unintentional grounds that violate the topology. If you have a device that requires a safety ground in the AC supply then you may need to isolate it e.g. using a DI box.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. Star grounding is a way get rid of ground loops caused by devices connected to different AC circuits, which is not what I am asking about. I am asking if there is a separate risk related to bussing the signal grounds of the guitar pedals I am using inside the patchbay.

Comment: Sorry, yes there is risk; any ground loop, power or signal, is effectively one turn of a transformer and so any cable that passes through the loop will couple a signal into the ground.  But if you can arrange a star topology then this can be largely avoided.  I say largely because signals can couple wherever conductors are in proximity to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the 'audio ground' is also the 'earth ground'.  If you use an ohmmeter and measure the resistance between the two, you'll often find a (nearly) dead short.   They're connected internal to your equipment.  Sometimes it is metal-to-metal, sometimes they're connected with a small capacitor.   Your ohmmeter would report a capacitively coupled ground as 'open' because to DC, it IS open. But to AC signals, this capacitor is basically a 'short circuit' (i.e. it doesn't break the ground loop you're worried about, it protects you from electric shock if your gear has a massive failure)

This means  you might have SEVERAL 'ground loops'.   Each piece of gear has an AC safety ground, and each has an audio ground.  If they're all tied together, well....

> > However, my understanding is that ground loops are created by connection of devices in the same signal flow path to separate AC power circuits (as shown in the image below), rather than by the internal low voltage patching of the devices

"Ground Loops" are literally what the name says .. A loop.  Anywhere you have a full loop of metal (or connected by capacitors), and any external AC fields (i.e. anywhere in the industrialized world) there WILL be an induced voltage around the loop.   The EFFECT this has on your equipment is what's hard to determine.  There's a big pile of 'it depends', and no single internet post will teach you how to know when it matters and when it doesn't. I mean, do you live on a farm, or do you live next to a radio transmitter???  Or maybe a hydroelectric power plant???  How is all the equipment you're connecting actually designed???  (Do they tie grounds or not)  Etc....

One key to controlling ground loops when they're unavoidable is to minimize the area of the enclosed loop.  Bigger area = more coupled noise.  If you were to wire all your AC stuff in a 'star' config, but you don't do same with your audio signals, you can end up with loops regardless.

> > > In my prototyping for this project I have been experiencing some noise issues when cables / pedals are left unconnected in the vicinity of the patchbay chassis, which seem to immediately disappear as soon as a ground connection is made between the various devices (my guitar amplifier and several guitar pedals powered by a one-spot 9V supply).

Are you gonna ground the patch-bay chassis???   If it's solidly grounded and made of metal, you can 'bus away' internally to it and you won't have any issues coupling external noise.  You might couple INTERNALLY generated noise, but if it's literally 'just a patchbay' and nothing else, you're probably good with a bus.

Comment: All good stuff.  Especially the expectation-tempering "There's a big pile of 'it depends'," where the real world often stomps on our best hopes.  I understand that pedals are often comprised of old school audio design and practices (from glances at YouTube videos).  So applying ideal star ground patterns may not be possible.  However, doesn't modern audio rack equipment use isolated digital signal paths (optical or Ethernet)?  That may help design ground pathways that can work from the middle out. Sketching it out with pencil and paper might help.

Answer (score 0):

Your depiction is correct. For example you connect the mains of  the mixer at one outlet and you connect amplifier mains to an outlet that is on different wall. By connecting the signal cables you have created the ground loop.

To avoid this, you have to use the mains supply from the outlets being close each to other, from single earth point.

The same rule applies to signals, by using a patch panel you do connect all signals in the same point. You have to avoid making circles with the cabling. As long you have guitar, mic,... on stub topology then no issues shall occur, the problem comes out if you unintentionally create a circle/loop.

Answer (score 0):

There is endless debate on this subject and, in reality, no one true way. (OK perhaps there is, but variations in the way inputs and outputs of different pieces of gear are wired and connected/unconnected to chassis mean you almost never manage it.)

Certainly a ground loop is a problem in a system where audio is passed between equipment unbalanced and unisolated, and grounds are connected both by signal cables AND the mains supply of different items of equipment (3 pin mains plugs). This *might* be the situation in the diagram you posted. BUT this is a worst case and (these days) rarely happens in practice (much gear only has 2 prong plugs, and/or balanced outputs are more common even with semi-pro gear). (It is also the reason that pro analogue installations will used balanced signal connections and, even isolation transformers - not so much so that grounds can be disconnected, but so that the signal interconnects are not ground referenced, which, in some ways, is the real root of the problem.)

The problem is that "star" topologies also can have issues : the local signal ground will be connected to local chassis ground somewhere, and chassis ground on different pieces of gear will have different potentials. If you measure potential between them you will see significant (in audio terms) amounts of mains and harmonics. And you still need to have a reference for your (unbalanced) signals.

However on a smaller setup such as you are describing, you are not worried about separate mains supply connections - you can power your setup off a single, clean, DC rail which has a solid earth reference. You should not have significant AC components in supply currents, and what there is will be related to the audio signal (i.e. not a "hostile" signal, like AC mains). You still need to pass unbalanced signals between equipment, and for that you need a good local reference both ends, with the minimum potential difference between.

A star ground might not be the best way to do that - and any potential difference between local grounds ends up added to your signal.

Simply grounding everything, everywhere to create a "mesh" ground, which will have, yes, ground loops, but many small ones with relatively small EMFs is as likely to be as good a way as any to make those unbalanced connections quiet.

This can depend on geometry - smaller loops are better - and trial and error might be necessary. The pragmatic approach is generally to connect every ground, but leave the possibility to lift here or there to try to solve any problems that may arise. Quite often this last step is unnecessary.

(Anyway, the noisiest thing in your system is probably your electric guitar - being high Z, unbalanced, coils, they ARE noisy, and pick up all kinds of RF - part of their charm, I'm told ...)

Answer (score 0):

As well as isolation transformers, balanced circuits, etc., another less used technique is to insert a low value resistor into a ground circuit to ensure there is only one low resistance path. This basically 'breaks' the audio earth loop. Sort of a last resort technique when all else fails. Not something you would inset into mains or safety ground circuits.